# Phonegap PushNotification, how to use my node push-server with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, cordova

So, i'm on Phonegap, i use :

- https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/
- https://github.com/argon/node-apn

So, i install the first plugin and i can get my phone token. After that, i created a node `server.js` file in my root directory with :

```
var apn = require('apn');

var token = "MY TOKEN";
var device = new apn.Device(token);

var notification = new apn.Notification();
notification.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;
notification.badge = 1;
notification.alert = "This is a Push Notification=)";
notification.payload = {'prop': 'special value'};
notification.device = device;

var options = {
 gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
 cert: 'CER.pem',
 key: 'KEY.pem',
 passphrase: 'password'
}
var apnsConnection = new apn.Connection(options);
apnsConnection.pushNotification(notification, device);
```

When i start my server with `node server.js` in command line, i can see my push notification on my phone, so all it's ok.

But my question, i need to send push notification in different place in my code (phonegap). How can i do that ?

When my `server.js` is running, how can i send other push notification from my phonegap application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have above is code that you can collect together, and expose a function to call it multiple times.  For example, a very simple implementation would be:

```
var apn = require('apn');
var options = {
    gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
    cert: 'CER.pem',
    key: 'KEY.pem',
    passphrase: 'password'
};
var apnsConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

module.exports.pushNotification = function(token, alert) {
    var device = new apn.Device(token);

    var notification = new apn.Notification();
    notification.alert = alert;
    notification.device = device;

    apnsConnection.pushNotification(notification, device);
};
```

Imagine you name this file `pns.js` for "push notification service".  Now in your `server.js`, you could instead `require` that module you just created and call the `pushNotification` function:

```
var pns = require("./pns.js");

pns.pushNotification("MY TOKEN", "This is a Push Notification");
```

Now you've got the same function when you execute the `server.js`.  From here, you could instead pull this function into other modules that need to call it from the Node.js side of things.

If you need to call it from a remote process, you could look into a web framework like [Express](http://expressjs.com/), and build an API which calls the same code.  The token and alert message could then be passed in to this function call.  Doing this would likely turn your `server.js` into a running web server which listens for requests and sends push notifications on demand.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for people with the same question, look at this tool:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushserver

...it does exactly what you want. It supports both iOS and Android.

Run this on a server and your app can: register the device by POSTing to http://yourserver:8000:/subscribe. Devices are stored in a mongodb database. By POSTing a http request to http://yourserver:8000/send, you can send push notifications to a single registered device, a subset or all of them.

Have fun!